# JqGrid navigation button function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, jqgrid

How can I implement [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing)?
How can I add a textbox and label and save it to the database? I'm using MVC3.

Comment: Why do you want to implement something that is already implemented!!! Why dont just use JqGrid?

Comment: I'm already using it..my question is how to set my parameters to the dialog that appearing after clicking the "Add,Edit,Delete" button..how to put textbox and label in the dialog??

Answer (score 0):

As your question is pretty general I can only offer some links to large sample projects:

- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)
- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC - Strongly typed helper](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)

The "Form Editing" functionality is covered in both, so you should find what you are looking for. If not please provide some more details to your question.